Uncaugh (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource
I'm new to the web development world and the video I'm using currently is trying to build a restaurant website, now h wants to add a payment method which is paypal I've done everything he's done and his own seem to work but mine doesn't. In my console i get Uncaugh (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource and in my network tab it's showing the route/undefined status code 400. Please anyone that can help me? here are my code
the controller
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Services\OrderService;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    function paymentIndex()
    {
        if (!session()->has('delivery_fee') || !session()->has('address')) {
            throw ValidationException::withMessages(['Something went wrong']);
        }

        $subtotal = cartTotalPrice();
        $delivery = session()->get('delivery_fee') ?? 0;
        $discount = session()->get('coupon')['discount'] ?? 0;
        $grandTotal = grandCartTotal($delivery);
        return view('frontend.pages.payment', compact(
            'subtotal',
            'delivery',
            'discount',
            'grandTotal'
        ));
    }

    function paymentGateway(Request $request, OrderService $orderService)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'payment_gateway' => ['required', 'string', 'in:paypal']
        ]);

        /**Create order */
        if ($orderService->createOrder()) {
            // Redirect user to the payment host
            switch ($request->payment_gateway) {
                case 'paypal':
                    return response(['redirect_url' => route('paypal.payments')]);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**Paypal paypal */
    function payWithPaypal()
    {
        return 'Payment processing...';
    }

    /**Paypal success */
    function paypalSuccess()
    {
        //
    }

    /**Paypal cancel */
    function paypalCancel()
    {
        //
    }
}


my blade file with the ajax script
@extends('frontend.layouts.master')

@section('content')

    <!--=============================
        BREADCRUMB START
    ==============================-->
    <section class="fp__breadcrumb" style="background: url({{ asset('frontend/assets/images/counter_bg.jpg') }});">
        <div class="fp__breadcrumb_overlay">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="fp__breadcrumb_text">
                    <h1>payment</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/') }}">home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;">payment</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!--=============================
        BREADCRUMB END
    ==============================-->


    <!--============================
        PAYMENT PAGE START
    ==============================-->
    <section class="fp__payment_page mt_100 xs_mt_70 mb_100 xs_mb_70">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Choose your payment getway</h2>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <div class="fp__payment_area">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1s">
                                <a class="fp__single_payment payment_card" data-name="paypal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal"
                                    href="#">
                                    <img src="{{ asset('frontend/assets/images/pay_1.jpg') }}" alt="payment method" class="img-fluid w-100">
                                </a>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4 mt_25 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1s">
                    <div class="fp__cart_list_footer_button">
                        <h6>total cart</h6>
                        <p>subtotal: <span>{{ currencyPosition($subtotal) }}</</span></p>
                        <p>delivery: <span id="delivery_fee">{{ currencyPosition($delivery) }}</span></p>
                        @if (session()->has('coupon'))
                            <p>discount: <span>{{ currencyPosition($discount) }}</span></p>
                        @else
                            <p>discount: <span>{{ currencyPosition(0) }}</span></p>
                        @endif
                        <p class="total"><span>total:</span> <span>{{ currencyPosition($grandTotal) }}</span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!--============================
        PAYMENT PAGE END
    ==============================-->


@endsection

@push('scripts')
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.payment_card').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            let paymentGateway = $(this).data('name');

            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '{{ route("checkout.payment.gateway") }}',
                data: {
                    payment_gateway: paymentGateway
                },
                beforeSend: function(){
                    showLoader();
                },
                success: function(response){
                    window.location.href = response.redirect_url;
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error){
                    let errors = xhr.responseJSON.errors;
                    $.each(errors, function(index, value){
                        toastr.error(value);
                    });
                },
                complete: function(){
                    hideLoader();
                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>
@endpush


my web.php route

use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminAuthController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\CartController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\CheckoutController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\DashboardController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\FrontendController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\PaymentController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\ProfileController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "web" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest'],function(){
    Route::get('default/login/admin', [AdminAuthController::class, 'index'])->name('admin.dashboard');
    Route::get('admin/forget-password', [AdminAuthController::class, 'forgetPassword'])->name('admin.forget-password');

});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'verified'], function() {
    Route::get('/dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'userDashboard'])->name('dashboard');
    Route::put('/edit-profile', [ProfileController::class, 'updateProfile'])->name('user.update.profile');
    Route::put('/change-password', [ProfileController::class, 'updatePassword'])->name('user.update.password');
    Route::post('/change-avatar', [ProfileController::class, 'updateAvatar'])->name('user.update.avatar');
    Route::post('profile/address', [DashboardController::class, 'createAddress'])->name('profile.address.store');
    Route::put('profile/address/{id}/edit', [DashboardController::class, 'updateAddress'])->name('profile.address.edit');
    Route::delete('profile/address/{id}/delete', [DashboardController::class, 'deleteAddress'])->name('profile.address.delete');
});

Route::get('/', [FrontendController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

/** Route to show product's images and info */
Route::get('/product/{slug}', [FrontendController::class, 'showProduct'])->name('product.show');

/**Product modal route */
Route::get('/product-modal/{productId}', [FrontendController::class, 'loadProductModal'])->name('product.modal');

//Add to cart route
Route::post('/add-to-cart', [CartController::class, 'addToCart'])->name('add-to-cart');

Route::get('/get-cart-products', [CartController::class, 'getCartProduct'])->name('get-cart-product');
Route::get('cart-product-remove/{rowId}', [CartController::class, 'cartProductRemove'])->name('cart-product-remove');

// Cart view route
Route::get('/product/view/cart', [CartController::class, 'viewCart'])->name('product.view.cart');
Route::post('/product/update/cart-qty', [CartController::class, 'updateCartQty'])->name('product.update.cart-qty');
Route::get('/product/cart/destroy', [CartController::class, 'destroyCart'])->name('product.destroy.cart');

/**Coupon route */
Route::post('/apply-coupon', [FrontendController::class, 'applyCoupon'])->name('apply-coupon');
/**destroy coupon route */
Route::get('/destroy-coupon', [FrontendController::class, 'destroyCoupon'])->name('destroy-coupon');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
    /**Checkout route */
    Route::get('/checkout', [CheckoutController::class, 'index'])->name('checkout');
    Route::get('/checkout/{id}/delivery-cal', [CheckoutController::class, 'calculateDeliveryCharge'])->name('checkout.delivery-cal');
    Route::post('/checkout/payment', [CheckoutController::class, 'checkoutRedirectPayment'])->name('checkout.payment');

    /**Payment route */
    Route::get('/checkout/payment/index', [PaymentController::class, 'paymentIndex'])->name('checkout.payment.index');
    Route::post('/checkout/payment/gateway', [PaymentController::class, 'paymentGateway'])->name('checkout.payment.gateway');

    Route::get('paypal/payments', [PaymentController::class, 'payWithPaypal'])->name('paypal.payments');
    Route::get('paypal/payment/success', [PaymentController::class, 'paypalSuccess'])->name('paypal.payment.success');
    Route::get('paypal/payment/cancel', [PaymentController::class, 'paypalCancel'])->name('paypal.payment.cancel');
});

require __DIR__ . '/auth.php';



I searched online and saw some stuffs about CORS tried using it but it didn't work, that's the only thing 'i've tried. Not: I'm using paypal sandbox api key in my database
